# What is the use of Media feature pack for N and KN versions of Windows 8.1?Also what is the N and KN editions in that?

Tags: windows-8.1, media

I was facing an issue connecting my device to Samsung Kies for which the service guys have responded to download the Media packs for N and KN versions of Windows 8.1.Now I don't understand what is this N and KNversions for which i opened the below link from Search

[Media Feature Pack for Windows 8.1 N and Windows 8.1 KN Editions: April 2014](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2929699)

After going through this huge amount of data I am unable to understand what exactly is its purpose.Will it effect the existing media software?

Comment: how's that for ya =D

Comment: Makes NO sense tho WHY samsung kies Needs WMP at all it has its own  built in tool for that and HAS for last 4 years.

Comment: thant's what I don't understand but still why do we have this version of Windows as a seperate media pack and not available as an update to a specfic geolocation

Answer (score 1):

Windows N version was / is to European market, does not include WMP. Windows K version is for Korean market, where local law requires Windows installation to put two Korean website shortcuts on desktop.

Windows KN version is a combination of these two: it installs two local, Korean website shortcuts and comes without WMP.

The Media Pack enables/installs Windows Media Player